# Como espero a que se actualice el valor de la variable sin setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, nextjs

Necesito esperar a que se actualice la variable antes de la primera y en cada iteración pero no puedo usar `setTimeout` porque cuando lo hago, algo muy importante deja de funcionar. Async await no es una opción en el momento en el que la variable obtiene su resultado.

```
  while(!resultsLength) {
        if (rebound > 3) break; 
        distance = POST_BODY.query.bool.filter[0].geo_distance.distance;
        distance = distance.slice(0, -2);
        variableForTheSakeOfIt = Number(distance) + 65;
        console.log(variableForTheSakeOfIt, 'before', typeof distance);
        variableForTheSakeOfIt = variableForTheSakeOfIt.toString() + 'mi';
        POST_BODY.query.bool.filter[0].geo_distance.distance = variableForTheSakeOfIt;
        console.log(POST_BODY.query.bool.filter[0].geo_distance.distance, typeof POST_BODY.query.bool.filter[0].geo_distance.distance);
        console.log(distance, 'after' , typeof distance);
        rebound++;
      }
```

Comment: Si traduces a Español podrás encontrar una respuesta. Please translate into spanish to find an answer.

Comment: Si traduces a Español podrás encontrar una respuesta. Please translate into spanish to find an answer. –

Comment: ¿Cual variable es la que necesitas actualizar? saludos